# Mysql SUM left join force show results with the sum of 0 zero results

Tags: mysql, left-join

So i am struggling with this for sometime now.

The employees just add start and end time on table `clocktimes`

I just want the result of all employees including the ZERO (the ones that didn’t show) also in that date interval. I also tried using COALESCE with no desired results.

The `regular` field is the amount of time already in units example : 3.5.

My problem is to show the ones that result is 0 (zero), no hours present in that task.

Query used:

```
SELECT
employees.employeeid,
employees.emp_external_id,
employees.status_id,
employees.firstname,
employees.middlename,
employees.lastname,
IFNULL(SUM(clocktimes.Regular), 0) AS sumoftime
FROM
employees
LEFT JOIN clocktimes ON employees.emp_external_id  = clocktimes.EmployeeGUID
WHERE
employees.status_id <> 3 AND
date(clocktimes.StartDate) BETWEEN '2017-07-01' AND '2017-07-15'
GROUP BY
employees.employeeid
ORDER BY
employees.firstname ASC
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d89534/1

Comment: Please post sample data, also post the full code, this would fail as multiple fields are not inside of aggregated functions and they are not grouped.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Done SQLfiddle, in working example " Aalbers Babu" should return 0 hours, that's my goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
employees.employeeid, 
employees.emp_external_id,
employees.status_id,
employees.firstname,
employees.middlename,
employees.lastname, 
IFNULL(SUM(clocktimes.Regular), 0) AS sumoftime
FROM
employees
LEFT JOIN clocktimes ON employees.emp_external_id = clocktimes.EmployeeGUID
WHERE
employees.status_id <> 3 AND
(date(clocktimes.StartDate) BETWEEN '2017-07-01' AND '2017-07-15') or date(clocktimes.StartDate) is null )
GROUP BY
employees.employeeid
ORDER BY
employees.firstname ASC
```

what is haapening here is, since you are filtering via date, null columns are being filtered out. **check the where clause**

Comment: Yes I am aware that the "where clause" with dates are restricting the results. I just want to include the  "absent" ones also. I am building a sqlfiddle as suggested.

Comment: Did you see the change I did in where clause?

Comment: I was traveling sorry! Your response Solves the problem (missing a '(' ) But it works. TY.